# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728

Tags: php, mysql

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 65488 bytes) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\moduloReportes\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\ReferenceHelper.php
>   on line 734

Comment: Hola buenos días, la cantidad de registros que tratas de subir de una vez es muy grande y el sql no lo los puede procesar, por lo que te recomiendo que lo subas en pequeños bloques por ejemplo de 100. Toma en cuenta que puedes tener un resto que tendrías que procesarlo a parte. Con **LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE**  puedes subir el fichero también te dejo el enlace para que lo veas. [enlace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/loading-tables.html)

Comment: Hola, podrias intentar con PDO, en ocasiones es mucho mas estable que mysqli

Comment: Es que ya no me permitia poner el error porque ya excedia la cantidad de caracteres xD muchas gracias por los consejos, los tomare en cuenta e intentare hacerlo :D gracias!!

Comment: no necesitamos ver tu query si no tu error! :v

Comment: jajjaaj TuT lo siento, ya subi el error

Comment: Daniel te marearon y la pregunta quedo incompleta. La misma tiene que tener tu error, el codigo que lo genera (no solo el sql, el codigo que usas por ejemplo para ejecutar ese sql). Asi como esta, la solucion es poner mas memoria.. pero no deberia. mira por favor [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solucion:
lo que sucede es que se exede la memoria limite para la ejecucion del script.
cambiarlo en `php.ini`

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

o la inicio de script con:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); // estable un limite de 512 megas
```

> recomiendo ir probando un limite de memoria y no anularlo ya que esto podria generar errores futuros

por si acaso anular el limite

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); // anula el limite
```

Comment: Exactamente. El propio error dice: `(tried to allocate 65488 bytes)` "Se intentó meter 65488 bytes de más" y no puedo. Sube la memoria como te dicen y se soluciona el problema. Al menos súbela 65Mb más, pero si es un script que va a estar moviendo muchos datos planteate lo que dice Bryro de anular la memoria para ese script, aunque puede tardar bastante en responder el servidor si debes mover muchos datos.

Comment: muchas gracias! por el apoyo, si es tardado pero resulto con exito!