# Error Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Necesito descargar unas fotos mediante unos links de un archivo de excel.

Estoy intentado hacerlo con la librería PhpSpreadsheets, haciendo un array que me recoja los links que hay entre cierto rango de filas y que con un foreach me vaya descargando cada foto.

Apenas intenté ver lo que me traía el arreglo una vez pasado por el foreach me salió el siguiente error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried
> to allocate 20480 bytes) in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\importacion_datos\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet.php
> on line 3108

Ya intenté subir la capacidad de la memoria en el php.ini, pero sigue apareciendo lo mismo.

Este es mi código hasta donde lo dejé:

```
<?php 

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$reader = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("test-data-import.xlsx");

$dataArray = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->rangeToArray(
        'AF:AK', NULL,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE       
    );

$array = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();

foreach ($array as $image) {
    echo $image[1];
}
```

Es la primera vez que intento hacer algo así, estaría bastante agradecida si pueden brindarme una solución a ese problema, o directamente explicarme una mejor manera de lograr descargar las fotos del archivo excel.

Gracias <3

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/241137/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728)

Comment: No, ya intenté cambiar el límite de la memoria y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: y estas imágenes son el link a una imagen o son el binario propiamente tal?